# Internationalization SQL/PHP/HTML

Tags: mysql, encoding, internationalization, set, character

I am attempting to learn about internalization in websites, so I am tampering with MySQL config file, field collations and html header character set type.
I basically have a form where I type some unicode characters in a text field, store it in a database, then output it back to the browser.
First scenario: HTML=>utf8 MySQL=>UTF8, that worked OK. However, when I viewed the database from PhPMyAdmin, weird characters were resident in the field.
Second scenario: I configured the VARCHAR in the database to be Latin1 by choosing a swedish_ci collation. The HTML remained utf8. I entered a unicode string in the form. Yet, the browser still displays the correct characters that I entered!!!

To make things more complicated for me to comprehend, I downloaded the mysql world database which is a database of all countries and cities of the world. The tables are Latin1 encoded. When I try to display them in a utf8 html, it displays weird characters for non-English characters. It works OK when my html character set is ISO-8591-1

Comment: what is your actual question?

Comment: how does the browser display the characters correctly when unicode characters are inserted in a Latin1 table?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using utf-8 you should allways use utf-8 for HTML, utf8 charset in MySQL and utf8_general_ci or utf8_unicode_ci for MySQL collation. And your php document must be saved as utf-8 without BOM.